# KDB+ Apply Conditional and then Update Multiple Columns in Table

Tags: functional-programming, kdb

I have a table with the following column names: `portfolio`, `tradeType`, `currency`, `security`, `tradeQuantity`, `tradeMV`, `totalTradeMV`, `transferMV`, and `adjustedMV`

I want to reduce the `tradeQuantity`, `tradeMV`, `totalTradeMV`, `transferMV` columns by the `adjustedMV`

Here is an example query:

```
odTradesAdjusted:update tradeQuantity:tradeQuantity-0f^adjustedMV,tradeMV:tradeMV-0f^adjustedMV,totalTradeMV:totalTradeMV-0f^adjustedMV,transferMV:transferMV-0f^adjustedMV from odTradesAdjusted
```

However, I want to do this only if the `adjustedMV` is less than the other columns. I could do a vector conditional using `?` for each of the columns, but is there a more elegant way of doing this rather than writing out the vector conditional 4 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use apply (`@`) with a little bit of subtraction logic:

```
@[t;`tradeQuantity`tradeMV`totalTradeMV`transferMV;{x-y*0<x-y}[;t`adjustedMV]]
```

Edit - this can be simplified to

```
@[t;`tradeQuantity`tradeMV`totalTradeMV`transferMV;{x-y*y<x}[;t`adjustedMV]]
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks so much. Can you explain how the subtraction logic works?

Comment: `x-y` gives positives when you want the subtraction to take place and negatives when you don't. So convert that to booleans using `0<` but then multiply the booleans by `y` to give zeros where you don't want the subtraction and gives the number to be subtracted where you do want the subtraction. Then just subtract. Easier to see it if you run it step by step from right to left with two simple lists

Comment: In fact it can be simplified a little further as per my edit above. Instead of checking `0<x-y` can check `y<x`